# jQuery mobile data-transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

In jQuery mobile, page transition effect is accomplished by setting data-transition properties i.e slideup slidedown, etc.

Is there a way to call the effect  using JavaScript?

Where is the complete API located at?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Define your transition handler:

function myTransitionHandler(name, reverse, $to, $from)
{
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    // Perform any actions or set-up necessary to kick-off
    // your transition here. The only requirement is that
    // whenever the transition completes, your code calls
    // deferred.resolve(name, reverse, $to, $from).

    // Return a promise.
    return deferred.promise();
}

// Register it with jQuery Mobile:

$.mobile.transitionHandlers["myTransition"] = myTransitionHandler;
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#page2" data-transition="myTransition">Page 2</a>
```

Look [here for more examples and transitions](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/Page-Transition-Plugins)

**Edit** Here are some APIs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/
- http://brooky.cc/2011/04/23/jquery-mobile-cheat-sheet/
- http://jquerymobiledictionary.dyndns.org/